# Group list of objects by precedessor/successor relationship?

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have objects of class A in a list.

```
class A
{
  public int Start;
  public int End;
}
```

I want to do a GroupBy on this list, so that each group contains only the objects that have a direct precedessor or successor in the same list (that is: obj.End + 1 = otherObj.Start). How can I accomplish this most elegantly with LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

I would order the list by `Start` and `End` and use a loop. This should work:

```
List<List<A>> successors = new List<List<A>>();
List<A> ordered = As.OrderBy(x => x.Start).ThenBy(x => x.End).ToList();
List<A> last = new List<A>(){ ordered.First() };
successors.Add(last);
for(int i = 1; i < ordered.Count; i++)
{ 
   A currentA = ordered[i];
   A lastA = last.Last();
   if (currentA.Start == lastA.End)
       last.Add(currentA);
   else
   {
       last = new List<A>() { currentA };
       successors.Add(last);
   }
}
```

LINQ is rarely the best tool if it comes to indices.